# How to change row-'value' every time i try to position a label using grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a terminal GUI using python tkinter module and I already managed to access the tk.Label from TextFrame class.

```
class TextFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()
        self.container = container
        self['bg']='black'
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
```

Now the problem is that, I can't change the row everytime I call show() function inside Instances class.

```
class Instances(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.string = tk.StringVar()

        self.index_row = 0

        self.text_frame = TextFrame(self)
        self.text_frame.pack()
        self.entry_frame = EntryFrame(self)
        self.entry_frame.pack(side='bottom',fill='both')

    def show(self, e):     
        textvar = self.string.get()
        self.entry_frame.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.text_frame.label.config(text=textvar)
        self.text_frame.label.grid(column=0, row=self.index_row, sticky="w")
        self.index_row += 1
```

Here is the full code of my problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry('800x600')
        self.title('Terminal')

                
class Instances(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.string = tk.StringVar()
        
        self.index_row = 0
        
        self.text_frame = TextFrame(self)
        self.text_frame.pack()
        self.entry_frame = EntryFrame(self)
        self.entry_frame.pack(side='bottom',fill='both')
        
    def show(self, e):     
        textvar = self.string.get()
        self.entry_frame.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.text_frame.label.config(text=textvar)
        self.text_frame.label.grid(column=0, row=self.index_row, sticky="w")
        self.index_row += 1
        

class TextFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()
        self.container = container
        self['bg']='black'
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        
        
    
                                    
                                    
class EntryFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self,  textvariable=container.string)
        self.entry.pack(fill='both')
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', container.show) 
                                                                                                                          
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Instances()
    window.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Problem Solved**

I added 1 line of code on show() function

```
def show(self, e):     
        textvar = self.string.get()
        self.entry_frame.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.text_frame.label = tk.Label(self.text_frame, fg='green', bg='black')
        self.text_frame.label.config(text=textvar)
        if len(textvar) > 0 :
            self.text_frame.label.grid(column=0, row=self.index_row, sticky="w")
            self.index_row += 1
```

Comment: Are you trying to change `self.index_row`? because that can be changed in in show(). What are you trying to change otherwise?

Comment: Do you want to move the label down one row whenever `show()` is executed?  However, even you increase `self.index_row` by one, the label is still at the top-left corner because there is no other widget above that row.

Comment: @AbhishekG yes. I want to increment the value of my self.index_row. The label will move down as the self.index_row increases by 1 value everytime show() is executed.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes. Hold on.. I will add some code where I tried to increment thr value of self.index_row.

Comment: I have said in my last comment that even the label is moved down by one row by increasing `self.index_row`, it will be still at the top-left corner of the frame because there is no other widget above it.  Note that row without any widget will have size 0.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for your comment. I finally got it. You gave me an idea where I made a mistake on making my terminal GUI. Thank so much!

Comment: Your solution is not moving the label down one row, you have created new label at the new row.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes. That's the mistake I'm trying to point out. I am trying to move down the label instead of creating another label that stack each other from the top. So the next time I create a label, it will move down.